# Save a captured image

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I have this piece of code (Just for experimenting) :

```
public void captureFromCam(View v) throws CameraAccessException {
    try {
        cm.openCamera("0", new CameraDevice.StateCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onClosed(CameraDevice camera) {
                super.onClosed(camera);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOpened(final CameraDevice cam) {
                Log.d("CameraApp", "Camera Opened");
                ImageReader ir = ImageReader.newInstance(800, 600, 256, 1);
                Surface surface = ir.getSurface();
                final ArrayList<Surface> l = new ArrayList();
                l.add(surface);
                try {
                    cam.createCaptureSession(l, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Log.e("CameraApp", "Configured");
                            CaptureRequest.Builder builder = null, b2;
                            try {
                                builder = cam.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            builder.addTarget(l.get(0));
                            CaptureRequest request = builder.build();
                            try {
                                session.capture(request, new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                                        Log.e("CameraApp", "Captured");
                                    }
                                }, null);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                        }
                    }, null);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {

            }
        }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The interesting part is `onCaptureCompleted`, as I understood result is somehow my picture.

How do I save this picture to a file? or if it is not my picture, where is my picture and how to I save it to file?

I am aware this question was answered but this is API 21 and it very different from the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I write a thread class to save pictures.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(ReaderListener, mHandler);
}

/**
 * diffrent formats to save diffrent pictures
 */
ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener ReaderListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
        Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        checkParentDir();
        File file;
        if (mFormat == ImageFormat.JPEG) {
            checkJpegDir();
            file = createJpeg();
            //here,maybe null, so trycatch
            try {
                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(bytes);
                try {
                    save(bytes, file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                image.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Exception e", "ImageFormat.JPEG,,,,,,,,Exception eException e");
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (mFormat == ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR) {
            checkDngDir();
            file = createDng();
            try {
                if (mDngCreator != null) {
                    mDngCreator.writeImage(new FileOutputStream(file), image);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Exception e", "mDngCreator.writeImage(new FileOutputStream(file), image)");
            }
            try {//image maybe null
                mDngCreator.close();
                image.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Exception e", "ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR,,,,,,,,Exception eException e");
                e.getStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what is "save(bytes, file);" ?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me, I have saved an image in ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener callback method. I have found this after some R&D, give it try.

Function call : saveImage(it.acquireLatestImage(), file)

```
/**
 * Save the image to storage
 * @param image Image object from OnImageAvailableListener
 * @param file File where image is going to be written
 * @return File object pointing to the file URI, null if the file already exists
 */

fun saveImage(image: Image, file: File): File? {
    if (file.exists()) {
        image.close()
        return null
    }
    val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
    val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
    buffer.get(bytes)
    val output = FileOutputStream(file)
    output.write(bytes)
    image.close()
    output.close()
    return file
}
```